# Why a unit set is not the same as its element? $\{x\} \ne x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was solving a list of exercises from homework and I answered one question wrong because I thought that a singleton set and its element were the same thing...

I found only a few results from a Google search:

https://www.google.com/#q=%22set+is+not+the+same+as+its+element%22

May anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: Just as an example: $\{x\}$ has exactly one element, namely $x$. However, how many elements $x$ has depends on $x$.

Comment: @Git Gud: Oh, sorry, the problem is that I often receive more than a good answer, I normally just UP vote them, and let the votes of other user decide which answer is the best (by receiving more votes than the others). But I will try to use the accept answer feature from now on.

Comment: @JoãoRimu That's a sensible approach. Do note, however, that I didn't tell you to accept any answer or anything, it's your choice. But I do recommend you accept some answers.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it can't *always* be the same. $\{\varnothing\}\neq\varnothing$. On the right-hand side, we have the empty set which has **no elements** but on the left-hand side we have a set which *does include an element*.

More generally, one of the axioms of modern set theory allows us to prove that no set is an element of itself. In particular $\{x\}\notin\{x\}$. Since the only element of $\{x\}$ is $x$, when we say $\{x\}\notin\{x\}$ we actually say that $x\neq\{x\}$.

Answer (score 4):

If a singleton set and its element were the same thing, then the set $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$, which has just *one* member, would be the same thing as the set $\{1,2,3\}$, which has *three* members.  Suppose one wants to enumerate the partitions of the set $\{1,2,3\}$.  They are:
\begin{align}
& \{\{1,2,3\}\} \\[6pt]
& \{\{1,2\},\  \  \{3\}\} \\[6pt]
& \{\{1,3\},\  \  \{2\}\} \\[6pt]
& \{\{2,3\},\  \  \{1\}\} \\[6pt]
& \{\{1\},\  \  \{2\}, \  \  \{3\}\}
\end{align}

The first partition listed has *one* part, not *three*.  That part has *three* elements, not *one*.

Answer (score 2):

A bag containing an orange is not the same thing as the orange itself.