# Are the elements $c$ and $\{c\}$ the same in a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a problem that asks me this:

If $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and $B = \{b, \{c\}\}$, is $B$ a subset of $A$?

What I'm confused about is if you treat $\{c\}$ and $c$ as the same elements.

I'm sort of confident that $\{c\}$ is distinct from $c$ and this would not be a subset, but I want to make sure.

Comment: $\{c\}$ is a set containing the element $c$.  So no, $B = \{b, \{c\}\}$ is not a subset of $A = \{a, b, c\}.$.

Comment: $\;c\;$ is an element, $\;\{c\}\;$ is **a set** containing one single element, namely $\;c\;$ , so no: they are not the same at all and thus $\;\{c\}\in B\setminus A\implies B\not\subset A\;$ ...and it is not a very good idea to use the exact same symbol for two different things...

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I appreciate it.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723377/why-a-unit-set-is-not-the-same-as-its-element-x-ne-x https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620616/what-is-the-difference-between-x-and-x-when-x-itself-is-a-set

Comment: Beware this problem may be more subtle... What I mean is, of course $c\ne \{c\}$, but what if $a=\{c\}$? So, without knowledge about $a,b,c$ we cannot tell.

Comment: c is a cookie, {c} is a cookie jar with one cookie.

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm sort of confident that $\{c\}$ is distinct from $c$ and this would not be a subset, but I want to make sure.

Be more confident.   It is so in *axiomatic set theory* that a set cannot be a member of itself.

---

As others have pointed out, it is *possible* that $a=\{c\}$, or even $b=\{c\}$; so we should make that cavat.$$\{b,\{c\}\}\nsubseteq \{a,b,c\}\text{ unless }a=\{c\}\text{ or }b=\{c\}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\{c\}$ is a set containing the element $c$, one is a subset of $A$: $\{c\} \subset A$, and the other is an element in $A: c\in A.$

So no, $B = \{b, \{c\}\}$ is not a subset of $A = \{a, b, c\}.$  $B$ is a set which contains an element of $A$ and a subset of $A$.  But since $\{c\} \notin A$, $B$ cannot be a subset of A.

Comment: Unless $a=\{c\}$... I cannot tell if that was envisaged by the author of the problem...

Comment: That's a good point you raise.  If in fact $a = \{c\}$, then indeed $B = \{\{x\}, a\}$, which means

Answer (score 1):

No it is not, since "$c$" in A is an element which different from $\{c\}$ in B where it is a set.